# How can I get the profile image of Windows Phone 8.1 owner's

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to get the Windows Phone User(Owner)'s picture. And there seems to be a proper Api [UserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx). I tried it but both code always returns null. I have profile picture in people app.(But I'm not sure this is the one mapped with `UserInformation`)

```
IStorageFile file1 = UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(AccountPictureKind.SmallImage);
IStorageFile file2 = UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(AccountPictureKind.LargeImage);
```

My environment is

- Windows Phone 8.1 Lumia 920 device.
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC

And I added application manifest also.

`xml
<Applications>
  <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe">
    <Extensions>
      <Extension Category="windows.accountPictureProvider" />
    </Extensions>
  </Application>
<Applications>`

Is there am I missed?

Comment: Kind weird - [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getaccountpicture.aspx) icons stand for Desktop and Phone, but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx#account_picture_provider) icon says *only desktop*. Also [provided example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Account-picture-name-sample-912baff1/) is only for Desktop.

Comment: I suppose your project targets Windows Phone 8.1, but is it a Windows Phone Silverlight Project or a Windows Phone project? (There is a difference)

Comment: There are no Windows Phone Silverlight Projects any more since Windows Phone 8. I guess the problem is that this API is supported on Windows Phone but the underlying API is not yet 100% mapped to the APIs from Windows 8.1

Comment: @andre The target is windows phone 8.1. Not silverlight 8.1

Comment: @DanielSteiner There very much is still Windows Phone Silverlight. Both for 8 and 8.1 no less. If you create a new project (or PCL), you can have it target them. You should also be able to make new Windows Phone Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this functionality does not currently exist on Windows Phone so the method will always return null. The icons on MSDN are fairly simplistic - they only indicate whether the method is present and callable on a particular platform, not whether it fully implements the expected behavior. Granted, there would ideally be a note in the remarks section indicating the difference in behavior.